# How to fire a ReactiveCocoa signal based on another signal?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I would like to fire a signal based on another signal firing. This is not really the same as combineLatest:reduce, because the 'trigger' signal cannot be easily KVO'd(it's a dictionary, and I need to observe the changes in the values).

Here's the problem I would like to solve, and I'd be interested to hear solutions:

I have a list of hierarchical data that needs to be displayed in a table view. In addition, this data can be filtered using a search string. So, I need to be able to search, and then collapse/expand data. So, I have:

```
// simple object that can have nested children
@interface ExpandableNode : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *children;
@end

// NOTE: The code below is highly simplified - no strongify/weakify, not making
// return objects immutable, etc. This should be seen more like pseudo-code as opposed to
// working production code.

// I'm assigning them directly here, but assume this comes from remote source
// eg. webservice.
self.results = @[@"Copenhagen", @"New York", @"Kuala Lumpur"];
self.childrenMap = @{@"New York" : @[@"Queens", @"Brooklyn"]};

// this dictionary keeps the expanded state, so when expanded, it looks like
// > Copenhagen
// ˅ New York
//     Queens
//     Brooklyn
// > Kuala Lumpur
//
self.isExpanded = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// this chunk of code returns an array of *unexpanded* nodes...
RACSignal *items = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, results), RACObserve(self, childrenMap)]
                                     reduce:^id(NSArray *results, NSDictionary *childrenMap) {
                                         NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
                                         for (NSString *item in results) {
                                             ExpandableNode *node = [[ExpandableNode alloc] init];
                                             node.name = item;
                                             if (childrenMap[item]) {
                                                 for (NSString *child in childrenMap[item]) {
                                                     ExpandableNode *childNode = [[ExpandableNode alloc] init];
                                                     childNode.name = child;
                                                     [node.children addObject:childNode];
                                                 }
                                             }
                                             [items addObject:node];
                                         }
                                         return items;
                                     }];
// ...and this code expands them out
RACSignal *flattenedItems = [items map:^id(NSArray *items) {
    NSMutableArray *flattenedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (ExpandableNode *node in items) {
        [flattenedItems addObject:node];
        if ([self.isExpanded[node.name] boolValue]) {
            [flattenedItems addObjectsFromArray:node.children];
        }
    }
    return flattenedItems;
}];

// when flattenedItems update, I reload my table view(handwaving alot here)
[flattenedItems subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Now, if I need to expand or collapse an item, I modify the 'isExpanded' dictionary. Ideally, only the second signal block fires, because my original, un expanded nodes have not changed. I only want to 'reload' the flattenedItems.

What I would like is a way to have a signal make another signal 'repeat' itself. but I'm unsure how to best tackle this.

Comment: How are you representing the expand/collapse events? Can you provide some more detail about that? Is that the same thing as the dictionary you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, expand/collapse events are being represented as a dictionary, with keys as unique identifiers to the headers that can be expanded and collapsed, and values as NSNumber representing BOOLs.

Comment: It seems that you're asking for the `sample:` combinator, but it's unclear (without seeing a bit more code) if that's actually the right way to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi guys, I've added some code to hopefully help explain my intent. After writing this code sample, it feels like what i really want is to combine the items signal with a dictionary change signal. But because I could not observe the dictionary with reactive cocoa, this was no-go. So I'm changing this dictionary somewhere else, and hoping to 'retrigger' the signal to flatten the items.